# azure SQL database not visable for co-admin

Tags: azure

db and sql db server created in my protal.
But the co admin cant see them how can i get the co admin to see them.

Erik-test (db-***(/****-test) is the azure sql-db/server

I can see them but the co-admin who needs to test with them cant.

How can i get them visable for the co admin

He is co admin on the subscription where the server and db are created under

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, the co-admin can't even see the service you created in the portal.Based on this official document [different administrator roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles#differences-between-azure-rbac-roles-and-azure-ad-administrator-roles):

> Classic subscription administrator roles
>
> Azure role-based access control (RBAC) roles
>
> Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) administrator roles

You could assign the `Owner` role for the co-admin person and that situation works well for me.(even though the document clarifies very clear:`The Co-Administrator has the equivalent access of a user who is assigned the Owner role at the subscription scope.` )